# multiple where clause sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Currently, I am using string manipulation for passing value for multiple where clause.

Since docs for raw queries with replacements does not support multiple where clause and i cannot use simply use a find()

Since my requirement needs complex mysql queries which is not possible using find().

Is there any  way of accomplish this basic task for multiple filtration  in "Raw queries mode" ?

```
   if(selector==""){
              selector="where "+searchkey+" LIKE "+"'%"+searchvalue+"%'";
}
else
{
              selector=selector+" and  "+searchkey+'  LIKE %' + searchvalue + '%';
}




sequelize.query('select ROLEID as RoleID,Rolename, CASE WHEN isactive = 1 THEN \'True\' ELSE \'False\' END as isactive , ' +
          'GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT modID) ModID,' +
          'GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Modulename) Modulename,' +
          'GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT  Accestype)  Accestype ' +
          'from ' +
          '( ' +
          'select isactive,rl.roleid AS ROLEID,n.modnameID as modID, n.Mname as Modulename,rl.rolename as Rolename, r.Accestype as Accestype  from mrole r ' +
          'left join modname n ' +
          'on r.modulename=n.modnameID ' +
          'left join role rl ' +
          'on rl.roleid=r.rolename '+
          ') as a '+selector+' GROUP BY ROLEID,Rolename,isactive '+ 
          'limit :NUMBER_OF_ITEMS ' +
          'offset :PAGE_NUMBER   ', {
              replacements: {
                  NUMBER_OF_ITEMS: parseInt(NUMBER_OF_ITEMS),
                  PAGE_NUMBER: parseInt(PAGE_NUMBER)
              },
              type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
          }
      ).then(function(projects) {
          var red = new Object();
          red.rows = projects;
          res.json(red);
      })
```

Comment: update your question to include the specific query you want to execute

Comment: i question is not in context with "specific query" but in general multiple clause using replacements simple ! just for clarification purposes i updated my question

Comment: A `replacement` is just a single value used in a prepared statement. Sequelize is an ORM with ActiveRecord pattern and a lot can be expressed through `find()`. If you want a query builder, use the `QueryGenerator` (undocumented!) or something else. You are not gaining anything here from using the ORM.

Comment: **More importantly: Stop doing string concatenation! You are exposing your app to SQL injection!**

Comment: what is a another way  of achieving "dynamic" multiple clause with complex query ? with or without orm

Comment: @felixfbecker i know what replacement  and find does which i already mentioned in POST  stop repeating. and it is simple question how to build "dynamic multiple clause using sequelize" or not .  any other pointers on how to achieve it is standard way !

Comment: @joshua.paling any pointers ???

Comment: ***ANY WAYS one can use sanitization function to check for SQL INJECTION BEFORE DOING "string concatenation" care to comment on that !***

Comment: ***@felixfbecker irony mate***                                       https://snyk.io/blog/sql-injection-orm-vulnerabilities/